# Transactional not working in many to many

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have problem with transaction in Spring MVC. I have 2 entities(User, Role) in ManyToMany. I have service where i want to get Roles of User:

```
public Set<Role> getUserRoles(long id) {
    Set<Role> roles = userRepository.findById(id).getRoles();
    return roles;
}
```

My User class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", referencedColumnName = "ID_USER") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROLE", referencedColumnName = "ID_ROLE") })
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
```

When i use this in my Controller:

```
Set<Role> roles=userService.getUserRoles(1);
    for (Role r : roles) {
        System.out.println(r.getName());
    }
```

i got a LazyInitializationException. Service is marked as @Transactional and method

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

in service method returns true.

```
public Set<Role> getUserRoles(long id) {
    Set<Role> roles = userRepository.findById(id).getRoles();
    for (Role r : roles) {
        System.out.println(r.getName());
    }
    return roles;
}
```

I noticed, that when I print roles in service then my controller works. 
Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

In controller i have code:

```
for (Role r : roles) {
        System.out.println(r.getName());
    }
```

When my service method is:

```
public Set<Role> getUserRoles(long id) {
    Set<Role> roles = userRepository.findById(id).getRoles();
    return roles;
}
```

then System.out.println(userService.getUserRoles(1)); in controller throw LazyInitializationException but when my service method is:

```
public Set<Role> getUserRoles(long id) {
    Set<Role> roles = userRepository.findById(id).getRoles();
    for (Role r : roles) {
        System.out.println(r.getName());
    }
    return roles;
}
```

then System.out.println(userService.getUserRoles(1)); in controller works

Comment: you explain when it works, but not when it does not work, and also not what "does not work" means, specifically (what happens, what should happen, error logs)

Comment: i updated my message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cinek181992, as you observed, when the System.out.println is done in the service it works, and it's because you're in the transaction, so the Role entity relations that aren't eager can be retrieved and printed. See that when it tries to read the attribute, it loads the attribute's data so it can be read next time in the controller.
That's because it fails in the controller, as the transaction has ended when the service has returned and the System.out.println on the data obtained tries to read entity attributes that has not been loaded in the transaction.

There are some solutions to your problem.
If @ManyToOne relations have to be read (usually are), mark them as EAGER.

Some times, and I prefer, is better not to work with entities out of the service layer, and send only DTO to the web layer.

Comment: OK, but the persistence strategy depends allways on your needs. Can you post the Role.java? It's where the one that causes your problem. And also what you need exactly of the Role on the view tier?

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` is probably only around your `userService`. That means that, when you exit the method, the transaction gets committed.

Later on, on your controller, you are trying to retrieve a lazy property of the entity (the user roles). As you are not in a transaction anymore, you get the `LazyInitializationException`.

If you want to retrieve the roles, either mark the controller as `@Transactional`, or retrieve the roles `eagerly`.

Comment: so if i want to get user's roles then i should use @Transactional or query to find it? I suspect that query is better choice